# Are there plans to integrate the #Dask dashboard in with project Juoyter

Tags: dask

Like many I am using Dask on a cluster with a Jupyter notebook. This means SSH tunnelling a port for Jupyter.

Tunneling one port is doable, more becomes problematic. I was wondering if there are plans to make a Jupyter extension for Dask so you can have a tab with all the nice Bokeh plots (or I may be missing something fundamental)

Or, (or in addition) I know you can get some visualizations like progress(future) is there a way to put more widgets inline with the notebook?

Specifically I am a massive fan of the profiling tools provided by #dask

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the development at https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension/pull/18 for jupyter-lab.

However, if you use the jupyter-hub proxy, then you can route calls to the dashboard via the same URL as the notebook - this is what is done by [pangeo](http://pangeo.io/), for example.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out

Comment: So By "same url" do you mean use the same port.. so you can just use the one tunnel?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I should have said "same port", but actually you tack onto the end of the URL to get proxied access to other ports on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here:

1. Placing dashboard plots within a JLab pane.  This is done in dask-labextension
2. Proxying connections over the Jupyter server connection.  This is done by nbserverproxy
3. Making all of this run smoothly and ironing out UX issues.  This is not done.  It would be great to have other institutions help with this.